# Does MySql load whole b+tree structure of indexes into memory, before usage?

Tags: mysql

MySql uses B+ tree to staore index data.
So MySql server start does it load whole B+ tree into memory before query or it read index data directly from disk?

Comment: If configured, MySQL will load entire ordered structure to memory. Otherwise it reads it from disk. It depends on the size of the index and how much RAM is allocated to MySQL (`innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable for `InnoDB`).

Comment: Not if it doesn't fit! But any sensible ISAM implementation will tend to keep nodes near the root in memory, just by normal caching action.